# How to connect data between author and book table which has ManyToMany relation in Django

Tags: python, django

I am learning Django and have been complete Model's chapter by "The Django Book" but didn't get the way to insert value in ManyToMany and ForeignKey for below question:

In this below model, How do i insert detail of `"Author"` and `"Publisher"` for `book name = "The book"` with `publication-date = "28/10/2013"`

And after inserting value, how do i get back `"Author"` and `"Publisher"` for `book name = "The book"`

```
class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 20, blank = True)
    email = models.EmailField(blank = True)

class Publisher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    state_province = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    website = models.URLField()

 class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    publication_date = models.DateField()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if book is already there in database.
just simply run like

```
book_obj = Book.objects.get(title="Test Title")   
author1 = Author.objects.get(name="test author1")
author2 = Author.objects.get(name="test author2")
author3 = Author.objects.get(name="test author3")
book_obj.authors.add(author1, author2,  author3)
```

Same you can add Publisher if book is already in database.

If you want to create new entry of book.

```
publisher = Publisher.objects.get(name='Test publisher')
author = Author.objects.get(name='Test author')
Book.objects.create(title='Title1', publication_date='28/10/2013', authors=author, publisher=publisher)
```

Comment: `p = User_content.objects.create(heading = request.POST['heading'], content = request.POST['content'], page_link = link);
   r = User.objects.get(username = 'bhaktanishant');
   r.page.add(p)`

Comment: When i am going with above code then an `AttributeError` occurred with value `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add'`

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to add a Stephen King's book Pet Semetary. You need to have the publisher and author instances already before adding the book object. Then it's very simple:

```
publisher = Publisher.objects.get(name='Simon & Schuster')
author = Author.objects.get(name='Stephen King')
new_book = Book(title='Pet Semetary', 
                publication_date='28/10/2013', 
                authors=author, 
                publisher=publisher)
new_book.save()
```

Is this the solution you were looking for?

**update on comment**

If the book object exists you can just apply it like so:

```
# create Author and Publisher:
new_author = Author(first_name='Stephen', last_name='King')
new_author.save()
new_publisher = Publisher(...bla bla...)
new_publisher.save()

# link them to your already existing book instance
book_instance = Book.objects.get(title='Pet Semetary')
book_instance.author = new_author
book_instance.publisher = new_publisher
```

Of course, you should use less general names than new_author or book_instance but you get the idea

Comment: Thanks for this, But what if book is already exist and we have to insert it's Authors(suppose multiple Author) and Publisher. THANKS IN ADVANCE.

Comment: Note that if you'r doing this through a form it's a different process. Also, check out @Sonu's answer on how to add new authors (my shown method would override any existing relationship)

Comment: So go to the django documentation about forms, look up how to use it with relationships (there's a huge section about it). Then, if you have trouble with it come back here to SO and post your form and your attempts and someone will help